# c program Warning the control reaches the end of non-void function

Tags: c++

so this is a simple c programming using recursion which returns the power of the input value, but for some reason it showing error

```
#include <iostream>
//int sum = 1;

int powerOfNumber(int n, int p) {
    if (n != 0) {
        p--; 
        return powerOfNumber(n , p) * n;
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::cout <<powerOfNumber(5, 2);
   

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: A good compiler would be able see that all control paths return a value.  But it's quite handy to get the warning, because this duplicated logic is code smell, and a style that should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int powerOfNumber(int n, int p) {
    if(p==0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return (n*powerOfNumber(n,p-1));     
}


int main()
{
    std::cout <<powerOfNumber(5, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Your `powerOfNumber` function never terminates because n is always 5.

Answer (score 1):

Your stop condition must be in terms of p, not n, because that's the variable you are substracting the value, either way you could substract the value of n

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug that the condition needed to be

```
    if (p != 0) {
    ...
    }
    if ( p == 0)
        return 0;
```

rather than     `if (n != 0) { ... } if ( n == 0) ...`.

But you might still get the same warning though if the compiler couldn't deduce
that there'll be always be a return.

You could simply rewrite it to:

```
int powerOfNumber(int n, int p) {
   if (p != 0) {
       p--; 
       return powerOfNumber(n , p) * n;
   }

   return 1;
}
```

so that there's always a return statement unconditionally.

P.S.: Be aware that if you are using a large input for either `n` or `p`, you might run to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).